# How do you make Dragonpunch and similar action?

Tags: street-fighter-iv

Maybe I am too new, but I found Dragonpunch's instruction quite confusing. It is a Right, a Down, a Right-Down. But how do you perform this with a PS3 analog stick or joystick?

What is the best way to do this? I don't know how you do it, but here is 2 thought of mine:

1) Right, move the stick back the center, Down, and Right-Down.

2) Right, move straigt to Down, then Right-Down. I suspect it will trigger a Right-Down while moving to Down. I use this method to do it. Am I wrong? Is this why I fail to perform Dragonpunch so often?

Comment: If there is a response that helped you, consider marking it as the 'answer' by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just push the stick right, then slide it down all the way along the curve, then slide it back right. It doesn't matter if the stick hits right after down right.

Looking at your numpad, the motion goes like this - 6323. Even if you do 63236 the input is still valid.

Comment: Go to training mode and activate "Input display". That will show if you are inputting another directions that are messing up your execution.

Answer (score 1):

just take a look at [this great guide](http://www.eventhubs.com/guides/2008/jul/08/street-fighter-4-strategy-guide-hints-and-tips/). choose a character ([ryu for example](http://www.eventhubs.com/guides/2008/jul/06/ryu-street-fighter-4-character-guide/)) and scroll down to "Special Moves" where all the available moves are listed with their key sequences/combinations.

Comment: He wasn't asking for a move list, he was asking how to do the shoryuken motion.

Comment: I noticed that after posting my answer but i thought i shouldn't delete it as it might be useful for other users that search for how to do special moves in streetfighter 4

Answer (score 0):

The motions are actually a bit more simplified in SF4.  Although it's listed as `F,D,DF`, you can actually just do `DF,D,DF` as a shortcut.  Especially helpful if you have a square-gate stick.

So to do the motion, you can just hold `Down+Forward`, swing over to `Down`, then swing back to `Down+Forward` and punch.  On a square-gate, it's pretty much `Down+Forward`, tap Backward (still pulling downward) and Forward then punch.

Otherwise if you have a round- or octagon-gate stick, you'll just have to get used to the motions.  You can still use the shortcut, it's just a heck a lot easier to do with a square-gate.

Comment: Really? Why the there are so many secret?

Comment: Yep, it should be that simple.